# DataBound ASP:CheckBox events not triggering as expected bacause of DataBinding occuring on Page_Load()

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, page-lifecycle

I am stuck into an ASP page.

The page contains an ASP:Container, containing several CheckBoxes.
I need to add an event on these CheckBoxes OnCheckChange so whenever we click one of the CheckBoxes, it unchecks all of the other checkboxes.
I could use a RadioButton, but using CheckBoxes has other advantages for me that are out of this subject so I do not want to use radio buttons.

That would theorically work fine just like this:

```
<ASP:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox id="MyCB" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="MyCB_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        <br/>
    </ItemTemplate>

    </ASP:Repeater>
```

and into the code behind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MyRepeater.DataSource=DS;
            MyRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }


  protected void MyCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       UncheckallOtherCheckBoxes();
    }
```

However, to have other regions of this page to work as expected, I do have to bind the DataSource on every page load and not only the first time.
So I need to change Page_Load to

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //   if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MyRepeater.DataSource=DS;
            MyRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And this causes everything to fail! :)
Because when I click on a checkbox, it triggers Page_Load before MyCB_CheckedChanged(). Si it DataBinds first and thus, the databinding sends some checkboxes events that are not the ones performed by the user.

Is there a way to solve this????

Thx in advance.

Comment: 1. Are you SURE you need to rebind the database each time the page is loaded? That's a bit unusual -- if you would care to explain your reasons it might help others understand better.

Comment: @Sandy: I think, because the container mentioned into the pose is nested into another Container.
If I do not re-bind the master Container on PostBack, I notice that all of the children Containers have no data.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your datasource later in the page lifecycle, if possible (onPreRender, for example). The control events for your checkboxes are handled after PageLoad and before PreRender and some other events. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for details.

Comment: I should have mentionned that the Container is nested into another Container. That is the Father Container that needs to be rebound for the checkboxes to be displayed on PostBack.


So same result if I move my binding into PreRender:

If I do not rebind my father Container, its datasource resets, there are no children containers, so no  MyCB_CheckedChanged method triggers.

If I only bind on PostBack=false, 
when checking a box, the page reloads, the father container does not rebind, and has no children. All checkboxes disappear and again no  MyCB_CheckedChanged event triggers...

Comment: In addition to the Page's PreRender event, there are PreRender events on most individual containers as well. Have you tried rebinding the parent container on it's own PreRender event, plus separately rebinding the child container on it's PreRender event. This way, the child container should be looking at an up-to-date parent, which is what you want.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you posted a small example of source code to illustrate the problem. It's helpful for the rest of us to understand better what you're doing. :)

Comment: Sandy, I still did not manage to have it to work but I managed to move one step forward. Since the latest findings went out of this post's scope, I made an updated post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922676/repeater-nested-into-a-repeater-causing-checkbox-oncheckedchanged-event-trigger
I wrote more detailed code in this update. 

I would love to get your opinion on this updated post if you have time to have a look :)